# Hold a unique pointer reference to a unique pointer reference

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers, destroy

Here is a program that represents my conceptual problem:

```
int main()
{
  unique_ptr<int> a = make_unique(5);
  {
    unique_ptr<int>& b = a;
  }
  printf("%d",*a);
}
```

- Is `a` the owner of the object?
- When `a` goes out of scope, does the value of *somepointer* get destroyed?

By running the above code I see it doesn't but I don't understand why. What exactly happens in the assignment?

Comment: `a` isn't out of scope when you print its ponitee (as evident by the fact you can name it). Why did you expect there to be a problem?

Comment: There are no assignments in this code, only one initialization and binding a variable to a reference. What are you expecting the reference `b` to do?

Comment: Do you know how references `&` work?

Comment: In your second bullet, don't you mean `b` and `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` remains the owner of the object this entire time.

In C++, placing `&` before a variable name creates a reference, which is like an implicit pointer. Since you've declared `b` as a reference, there is only ever one `unique_pointer` in this code. `a` is the `unique_pointer` itself, and the **reference** `b` points to that pointer.

This is the reason the `unique_pointer` is not destroyed when the block containing `b` is exited; `b` never owned the resource because `b` was never a `unique_pointer` to begin with, only a **reference** to one.

See [learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/611-references/) for a full lesson on references.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment to `b` is simply a reference, it has no bearing on the object lifetime of `a`. Imagine instead that you had passed a to a function taking a `unique_ptr<int> &`, you wouldn't expect the reference to alter the lifetime of a in that case, why would you do so here?